# get a list of cities from location model and how many locations exist for each city

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a location model which has a few columns:  title, address, city, state, etc...

I am trying to show a list of all the cities based on the locations in my database.  Then, I am trying to figure out per city how many locations there are.

I want to be able to output something like

```
Tampa(10) 
Denver(20)
Atlanta(15)
... and so on
```

Currently to get a list of cities in the database I am using the following code:

```
cities = Location.uniq.pluck(:city)
```

Technically I could loop through all the cities and do a COUNT(*) WHERE city = "cityname"... but that seems like a very inefficient way to do this.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this for faceted navigation?

Comment: @MarkThomas It could be, I am still working through ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Location.group(:city).count
```

This will give you a hash with city as the key and value as the count

Answer (score 1):

you should use a GROUP BY insted

```
SELECT city, COUNT(*) FROM locations GROUP BY city;
```

Comment: I am relatively new to Rails, is there a way to do through this ActiveRecord.

Comment: I only know SQL, but looks like Vimsha have the Rails version of above query

Comment: Yep, you are right, your SQL is perfect.  My main battle with rails is converting SQL to ActiveRecord :)